# Consolidating CSS classes into one custom class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to take:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
```

And change it to:

```
<button class="btn btn-foo">
```

...with...

```
.btn-foo { 
    /* apply .btn-primary */
    /* apply .btn-block */
}
```

Comment: If you use SASS/SCSS, you could apply the style to another.

Comment: Kind of... Would I have to use a custom id to apply multiple classes instead of using a custom class to apply multiple classes?

Comment: You do not need any id to apply multiple classes. You can just put as many classes as you like into the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do so with SASS pre-processor by using @extend.

```
someDiv { @extend .opacity; @extend. 
.radius; }
```

Otherwise, you could use JavaScript (jQuery) as well:

```
$('someDiv').addClass('opacity radius')
```

Comment: I forgot I could do that with jQuery! Thank you!

Comment: Appriciate a vote count, if you are satisfied with answer, thanks